# How to bind an event only after it loses binding before

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

I have a div on which I bound `click` like this:

```
  $("#mydiv").one('click',function(){ ... });
```

Because I want to execute an action only one time.
Now I wanto to re-`bind` it

```
  $("#mydiv").on('click',function(){ ... });
```

But only if the users clicked on it , at least the first time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean, first click gives action-A, then subsequent clicks give action-B?

Comment: exactly  , I have to execute an append then I don't need anymore then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [namespace events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) with jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click.firstClick', function () {
    // do stuff for the first time
    $(this).off('click.firstClick'); // only removes this event
});

$('#mydiv').on('click', function () {
    // stuff that always happens when you click
});
```

If you simply want to have something happen the first time and then something happen every time after that:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    // stuff that happens the first time you click
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).click(function () {
        // stuff that happens every time after this
    });
});
```

Example of first scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/75HWV/
Example of second scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/SbhY3/

Comment: I'm gonna try It, Let you know in a couple minutes. I guess it will do my trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mydiv').one('click', function() {
    // ...
    // code here for action-A, on first click
    // ...
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        // ...
        // code here for action-B, on subsequent clicks
        // ...
    });
});
```